# Electronics by Example

Tags: dc, basic

I am interested in learning more about electronics. I know some basics about resistors, capacitors, transistors, and diodes. I would like to learn more about things such as operational amplifiers, transformers, and more, but I don't know where to begin. I prefer to learn by example, I am not against books or that style of learning, but I feel examples are necessary to complement them at the least.

I am interested in kits (since learning requires various parts and I'd not like to buy them one at a time) which do not require solder (because it often makes parts one-time-use). I have looked into Arduino and similar kits but I feel they miss the point. I feel it is of more use to a veteran engineer than someone wanting to learn. I feel too many steps are missed and it falls off at being nothing more than teaching basic connections and perhaps design theory (the theory of how something could be made without explaining how it works).

Also, while I am interested in PICs, uCs, and more, I am currently more interested in learning what can be done without them. I feel too many kits which include these pieces fall back into design theory. That is, they almost introduce them like magic rather than explaining why they work. This leaves you with a circuit which you have built, but don't understand.

So, my question is, where can someone begin to learn more about DC electronics without feeling that something is missing? I am interested in project ideas as well as kits.

Comment: The 'bible' of electronics, the book by Horowiz & Hill, is full of examples!

Comment: Art of Electronics, Horowitz and Hill, 1980. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Electronics

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you want to get a series of books by Forrest M Mimis III, starting with [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0945053282) and continuing with [his others](http://www.amazon.com/Forrest-M.-Mims-III/e/B003UGHJVE/ref=dp_byline_cont_book_1).  The book mentioned in a comment to another answer ("Art of Electronics" by Horowiz & Hill) is a college textbook, and being so, costs a pretty penny ($120 at Amazon) and may be too technical to start with.

Then I would get one of these "all-in-one" electronic kits.  Most seem to be designed to be used with an Arduino or Raspberry Pi, but there are still ones that are stand-alone, such as the ones [sold here](http://www.amazing1.com/categories/kits/all-in-one-electronic-lab-kits.html), the best being the [500-in-one at $233](http://www.amazing1.com/products/500-in-1-electronics-lab.html).  The nice thing about this store, is that you can browse any of the manuals and see what the projects are.